# Should I always index all entries of a join table?

Tags: sql

Should I always index all entries of a join table?

I imagine that there is not much benefit to indexing both columns together, and each column should have its own index?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  I have no idea what you mean by "a join table".

Comment: @DanBracuk http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_table will probably shed light on this little known and super-rare database concept.

Comment: @bharal To be fair that wiki article does redirect to junction table and lists about a dozen other terms for it.

Comment: @MartinSmith I know, but I'm not aware of "join table" really having any other connotation, especially given the "sql" tag. Or am i (as i am, often) wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about a many to many relationship table I normally do

```
CREATE TABLE FooBar
(
FooId int NOT NULL REFERENCES Foo(FooId),
BarId int NOT NULL REFERENCES Bar(BarId),
PRIMARY KEY (FooId, BarId ),
UNIQUE (BarId, FooId )
)
```

On the grounds that this both ensures no duplicate rows are added and will (in SQL Server and probably all RDBMSs) implicitly create a composite index on both `FooId, BarId` and `BarId,FooId` and usually you will want to seek in either direction to either get all `Bar` for a `Foo` or vice versa.

The two composite indexes created will cover those queries .

Comment: Yes. This table layout gives only two possible indexes, so you can just create all of them. Single-col indexes would be extended under the hood to 2 cols anyway.

Comment: @usr - Yes in SQL Server they would. I'm not sure that is true in all RDBMSs though and the OP hasn't specified a particular one. Even if the single column index was narrower (say `FooId` + row locator vs `FooId, BarId` + row locator) the single column one would probably  only be advisable if you *never* lookup `BarId` by `FooId` and purely need the single column one to make FK validation more efficient.

Comment: @MartinSmith how would i determine if sqllite supported this composite index creation on FooId, BatId and BarId,FooId given the create statement you, well, gave?

Comment: @bharal I've never used SQLite but the answer here indicates it does create indexes for these constraints http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/does-a-unique-constraint-imply-an-index-td37361.html